# New design: should we have more contrast?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

I hate to be acting like Goldilocks, but it seems to me that the color scheme in the new design has too little contrast. I would have preferred the question titles to be the blue used for "MATHEMATICS" in the masthead. Or the red used for "meta" in the meta masthead. The grey used for tags etc. also is too light to be comfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.